# Better way to handle multiple instances on AppFog when using Yii's CAssetsManager

Tags: php, yii, amazon-s3

If you are running an Yii-app on Appfog with mulitple instances, and you are using CAssetsManager for your static files, you will (at least I did) experience issues with broken links to static files.

I concluded that the reason is that each instance on AppFog will have a different paths to each asset. Here's an example.

**Instance 1:** `/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/54dc7546ac14/app/protected/assets/logo.png`

**Instance 2:** `/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/54dc7546ac14/app/protected/assets/logo.png`

**Instance 3:** `/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/54dc7546ac14/app/protected/assets/logo.png`

When Yii publishes these assets they will get different paths, since each path is based on a hash that is based on `dirname()` returned by the function [generatePath()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/CAssetManager.php#L325). I know about the option `hashByName`, but setting it to true will share the published path among different extensions.

Therefore the public path to the `logo.png` will have three different possibilities:

**Instance 1:** `https://www.example.com/assets/fb4gf4ac45/logo.png`

**Instance 2:** `https://www.example.com/assets/ab4ed4f394/logo.png`

**Instance 3:** `https://www.example.com/assets/fde07233bc/logo.png`

The **implication** will be that when requesting **www.example.com** a arbitary instance will handle the request. Let's say it is *instance 1*, which will give a response with a link that refers to `https://www.example.com/assets/fb4gf4ac45/logo.png`. The link will trigger a second request, and this time another arbitary instance will handle the request (*instance 2*).

The problem is that the instance 2 cannot find `assets/fb4gf4ac45/logo.png`, since the file on this instance is located at `assets/ab4ed4f394/logo.png`.

This **can be handled** by using the [S3AssetsManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/s3assetmanager/), but it will still upload assets for each instance to S3, and that makes the site slow every time the codebase is updated. It also results in A LOT OF assets paths on S3.

**THE QUESTION:**

So, even though I do have a work around I wonder if there is **a better way to handle multiple instances on Appfog** without changing the Yii-source code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options. Aaron Francis' solution here is pretty nifty, but requires a fair number of moving parts:
http://aaronfrancis.com/blog/2013/6/19/yii-and-the-asset-pipeline-part-2

It's also the most complete solution I've run into.

The second option is Jadon Hancock's available here. I've ended up adapting this to fit a project I'm working on. Not as elaborate or complete, but it was good enough for what I needed to start with. I may revisit Aaron's solution in the future. 
https://gist.github.com/jasonhancock/5073938

Comment: Aaron's solution do have a fair number of moving parts. Jadon Hancock's solution using a version number is interesting, but I don't like that it adds manual work every time the code based is updated. But it made me realize that I (of course) can extend the CAssetsManager and then use the webroot as the hash-source instead of dirname() + filemtime(). I'll give that a try!

Comment: If you do get something going that you like, would you mind posting it on Gist and letting me know? Would love to see some nicer code ;-)

Comment: Yes! I will base it on this extension: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/s3assetmanager/)